# Jenkins: Appium: Command not found

Tags: linux, jenkins, command, appium

Installed Appium to Linux machine with npm and it was added to user FOO home folder. And now when Jenkins user is trying to run 'appium' command, it says command not found.

For FOO user there is path set in ~/.bash_profile , I assume this is that one:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
```

Is there a way that Jenkins could execute 'appium' command? Where exactly and how should I create this new path for Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

Add at the beginning of the jenkins execution script command line:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -il
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running as a build step : Execute shell:

```
appium --session-override
```

Answer (score 0):

run command:

`which appium`

it will print path, then provide this path in bash_profile for jenkins user (/Users/jenkins/.bash_profile)